# mobile app developed with phonegap and jquery mobile showing blank screen when deployed on device

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing a mobile app in Android using phonegap and jquery mobile. It's running fine on Emulator. But when deployed to device, It's just showing an empty white blank screen. I had edited config.xml to include access origin=".*" and edited manifest to include sufficient permissions. I referred some questions and I edited my html files so that the javascript functions will be fired on device ready event only. Still I am not able to figure out the solution to run app on device. I am using cordova 2.4. Any suggestions are appreciable. Pls help.

Comment: Does using `access origin=".*"` really open it up to everything, or is it expecting the first character in your network calls to be a `dot`?  What if you switched it to `access origin="http://*"`, or even just `access origin="*"`

Comment: @Tom, actually I included both access origin=".*" and access origin="*". still facing the problem

Comment: Just to rule out further network issues, is this an internal application or is your service openly accessible?  That is, do you need to be connected to VPN to access your data?  If so, are you connected via the phones VPN?

Comment: I am trying to access localhost using 10.0.2.2 does this need internet of device to be enabled ?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with that IP (Google tells me it's the Android emulator), but I'd imagine yes, you need to be connected to the internet and if you are getting data from somewhere that is only hosted internally, you will need to be connected to the same WiFi or VPN that the server is hosted

Comment: I changed the address from 10.0.2.2 to 192.168.1.X and now I am able to access it. @Tom thanks for ur help

Answer (score 0):

If your program runs on emulator under Windows, but does not work properly on real device, 
the problem source can be in the Android OS case sensitivity.

E.g. you have real file in your root with name:

```
Home.js
```

and you have the following line in the index.html file

`<script type="text/javascript" src="home.js"></script>`

this line will work fine in Windows, but not in Android.

In order to work properly under all OSes, it should be written case-sensitive:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="Home.js"></script>`

Comment: I changed the address from 10.0.2.2 to 192.168.1.X and now I am able to access it. @TSV thanks for ur help